# how to add default option value from dropdown using mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In dropdown am fetching the value from the database i't is working fine ..i need to add `<option value='-1'>Root</option>` by manually which is not present in the database.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Domain Name</label>
      @Html.DropDownList("DomainID", null, "--- Select Domain Name ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.DomainID, null, new { @style = "color: red" })
    </fieldset>
   </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">
     <fieldset class="form-group">
       <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Parent Module</label>
          <select id="ParentModuleID" class="select2-arrow" name="ParentModuleID"></select>
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.ParentModuleID, null, new { @style = "color: red" })
     </fieldset>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#DomainID").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $("#ParentModuleID").empty();
        $.get("ParentModule_Bind", { DomainID: id }, function (data) {
            var v = "<option>--- Select Domain Name ---</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#ParentModuleID").html(v);

        });
    });
```

in above jquery `<option>--- Select Domain Name ---</option>` i need to add root with `value of -1`

```
public JsonResult ParentModule_Bind(string DomainID)
        {
            userType type = new userType();
            DataSet ds = type.ParentModule_Bind(DomainID);
            List<SelectListItem> statelist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["ModuleName"].ToString(), Value = dr["ModuleID"].ToString() });
            }
            return Json(statelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: There  are many ways to do this .I had this problem .The Best way and best practice  is add your manual value in Controller .  cheerz!!

Comment: below my answer is working fine ..is it correct or not @Floxy

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a line in jQuesry like this

```
v += "<option value='-1'>root</option>";
```

or add a line in controller above `foreach` like this

```
statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "root", Value = "-1" });
```

to achieve the result.

Comment: in your code displaying root value only but database value is not showing

Comment: Put the line (I suggested) above the `foreach` statement and leave everything as it is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do any of this in the UI with jQuery?

One big problem I see is that your are mixing business logic of your list data with UI manipulation.

If this value is always needed for the ParentModel list regardless of DomainID, then I'd modify you method that returns you the list

```
public JsonResult ParentModule_Bind(string DomainID)
{
    userType type = new userType();
    DataSet ds = type.ParentModule_Bind(DomainID);

    //change the following line

    var statelist = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Root", Value = "-1" };
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
       statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["ModuleName"].ToString(), Value = dr["ModuleID"].ToString() });
    }

    return Json(statelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```